# Kill connection in pgadmin4 Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin, pgadmin-4

Can you tell me how to kill connection in pgadmin 4 web postgresql without executing any scripts?

How can I limit the number of connection to database in order to kill the active connection (My case I want to rename database already used !)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**pgAdmin III** can show information about all connections by using the `Tools > Server Status`. This option shows a window with four panes:

1. Acitivity (showing all connections, with PID, application name, database, user, etc). In this pane, you can select one connection and either `Cancel the query` or `Stop the backend` by means of two little orange and red buttons. These correspond to [`pg_cancel_backend`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADMIN-SIGNAL-TABLE) and [`pg_terminate_backend`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADMIN-SIGNAL-TABLE) PostgreSQL function calls.
2. Locks
3. Prepared transactions
4. LogFile

pgAdmin III, when choosing a Database Cluster from the Object Navigator, will show, under the `Statistics` tab, all connections with their running queries.

---

**pgAdmin 4**, on the other hand, does *not* have a `Tools > Server Status` menu. Instead, it's got a `Dashboard` tab, which has the same functionality, except for three things:

1. The `Sessions` tab (equivalent to the `Sessions` pane in pgAdmin III) does *not* have any buttons. So, the functionality to cancel a backend is by means of the GUI is not there.
2. THe `LogFile` functionality is not present. I assume this is due to the new architecture of pgAdmin 4, that works as if you were remotely connecting through a web server, which is supposed to *not* have access to local files, but only to the database. The database itself writes on the log files, but it does not read from them.
3. There is also a `Configuration` tab, shown when selecting the database cluster, showing all values from `postgresql.conf` (through database calls, I assume).

The statistics tab is also present, with euivalent functionality.

---

NOTES: Checked on pgAdmin III v 1.22.2  and pgAdmin 4 v 1.4

Comment: "So, the functionality to cancel a backend is by means of the GUI is not there" - great

Comment: Can we just use pgAdmin 3 for this?